# Uniform generation of permutation with repetition at most $k$ times.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, random

We have set $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots,n\}$ of numbers. We want to generate permutation of length of $m$ created of those numbers with repetition of each number at most $k$ times.

If we assume $n=5, k=2, m=3$, then we could receive: $$\{3,3,1\},$$ but not $$\{3, 3, 3\}$$ as $3$ in the second example happens to be three times in output, which is more than $k$.

Is there a way of uniform generation of such permutation in a fast way?

Comment: Generate a permutation with repetition. Reject if some number is repeated more than $k$ times.

Comment: I did, it's really slow as complexity of it is $O(\frac{n}{p})$, where $p$ is probability which decreases quickly (faster than $e^{-n}$.

Comment: When you say "permutation" are you saying $(3,3,1)$ and $(1,3,3)$ are different?

Comment: Yes, they are different for me. Should I call it with some other name?